# Meaning of 'man, please'

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was watching the TV series of 'Running wild with Bear Grylls' who is a survival expert in the wild. In the show, he goes the wild with celebrities. The show goes to the extreme of eating worms, bats, snakes, etc to survive. This is a conversation between Bear and the celebrity.

> Bear: So did you ever do this sort of thing?
>
> Male guest: Man, please.

So the guest obviously doesn't have experience with this sort of survival thing. But I'm not quite sure why he has to answer with 'please' there. He can simply answer 'I haven't had'. What's his attitude by putting 'please' with his answer there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both these words are interjections expressing surprise.  "Man!" is used when addressing a man to place emphasis. And "please" is a mild expression of annoyance.  "Please (don't ask me that, because it's obvious that I've never done anything like this before)"